# Box-plot R calculating outliers

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

```
> summary(mydata)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0      93     107     110     125     197 
> range=1.5*(125-93)
> upper_whisker=125+range
> lower_whisker=93-range
> upper_whisker
[1] 173
> lower_whisker
[1] 45
> boxplot(mydata)$stats
  [,1]
[1,]   56  #Lower whisker by boxplot
[2,]   93   
[3,]  107
[4,]  125
[5,]  173
```

I tried looking up the formula for calculating after and before what values are the points to be considered outliers
It was

```
 Above =>3rd Qu +(3rd Qu - 1st Qu)*1.5
 Below =>1st Qu -(3rd Qu - 1st Qu)*1.5
```

For some reason they don't seem to match with the stats returned by boxplot function in R
I have a feeling it's something silly here

Are they calculated differently? Or am I reading the wrong answer from boxplot?

Edit:

I've used https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database
and ran

```
mydata=raw$Glucose[raw$Outcome==0]
```

EDIT2:[image: The Box-plot]

I suppose if

```
#max(min(x), Q1 - (IQR(x)*1.5)) #lower whisker
```

is returning min(x), there shouldn't be any outliers
and min(mydata) is 0

Edit 3:
Clearer view of Quantile

```
quantile(mydata)
0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
0   93  107  125  197
```

Edit 4:
 Added vector as requested

```
c(85L, 89L, 116L, 115L, 110L, 139L, 103L, 126L, 99L, 97L, 145L, 
117L, 109L, 88L, 92L, 122L, 103L, 138L, 180L, 133L, 106L, 159L, 
146L, 71L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 88L, 150L, 73L, 100L, 146L, 105L, 
84L, 44L, 141L, 99L, 109L, 95L, 146L, 139L, 129L, 79L, 0L, 62L, 
95L, 112L, 113L, 74L, 83L, 101L, 110L, 106L, 100L, 107L, 80L, 
123L, 81L, 142L, 144L, 92L, 71L, 93L, 151L, 125L, 81L, 85L, 126L, 
96L, 144L, 83L, 89L, 76L, 78L, 97L, 99L, 111L, 107L, 132L, 120L, 
118L, 84L, 96L, 125L, 100L, 93L, 129L, 105L, 128L, 106L, 108L, 
154L, 102L, 57L, 106L, 147L, 90L, 136L, 114L, 153L, 99L, 109L, 
88L, 151L, 102L, 114L, 100L, 148L, 120L, 110L, 111L, 87L, 79L, 
75L, 85L, 143L, 87L, 119L, 0L, 73L, 141L, 111L, 123L, 85L, 105L, 
113L, 138L, 108L, 99L, 103L, 111L, 96L, 81L, 147L, 179L, 125L, 
119L, 142L, 100L, 87L, 101L, 197L, 117L, 79L, 122L, 74L, 104L, 
91L, 91L, 146L, 122L, 165L, 124L, 111L, 106L, 129L, 90L, 86L, 
111L, 114L, 193L, 191L, 95L, 142L, 96L, 128L, 102L, 108L, 122L, 
71L, 106L, 100L, 104L, 114L, 108L, 129L, 133L, 136L, 155L, 96L, 
108L, 78L, 161L, 151L, 126L, 112L, 77L, 150L, 120L, 137L, 80L, 
106L, 113L, 112L, 99L, 115L, 129L, 112L, 157L, 179L, 105L, 118L, 
87L, 106L, 95L, 165L, 117L, 130L, 95L, 0L, 122L, 95L, 126L, 139L, 
116L, 99L, 92L, 137L, 61L, 90L, 90L, 88L, 158L, 103L, 147L, 99L, 
101L, 81L, 118L, 84L, 105L, 122L, 98L, 87L, 93L, 107L, 105L, 
109L, 90L, 125L, 119L, 100L, 100L, 131L, 116L, 127L, 96L, 82L, 
137L, 72L, 123L, 101L, 102L, 112L, 143L, 143L, 97L, 83L, 119L, 
94L, 102L, 115L, 94L, 135L, 99L, 89L, 80L, 139L, 90L, 140L, 147L, 
97L, 107L, 83L, 117L, 100L, 95L, 120L, 82L, 91L, 119L, 100L, 
135L, 86L, 134L, 120L, 71L, 74L, 88L, 115L, 124L, 74L, 97L, 154L, 
144L, 137L, 119L, 136L, 114L, 137L, 114L, 126L, 132L, 123L, 85L, 
84L, 139L, 173L, 99L, 194L, 83L, 89L, 99L, 80L, 166L, 110L, 81L, 
154L, 117L, 84L, 94L, 96L, 75L, 130L, 84L, 120L, 139L, 91L, 91L, 
99L, 125L, 76L, 129L, 68L, 124L, 114L, 125L, 87L, 97L, 116L, 
117L, 111L, 122L, 107L, 86L, 91L, 77L, 105L, 57L, 127L, 84L, 
88L, 131L, 164L, 189L, 116L, 84L, 114L, 88L, 84L, 124L, 97L, 
110L, 103L, 85L, 87L, 99L, 91L, 95L, 99L, 92L, 154L, 78L, 130L, 
111L, 98L, 143L, 119L, 108L, 133L, 109L, 121L, 100L, 93L, 103L, 
73L, 112L, 82L, 123L, 67L, 89L, 109L, 108L, 96L, 124L, 124L, 
92L, 152L, 111L, 106L, 105L, 106L, 117L, 68L, 112L, 92L, 183L, 
94L, 108L, 90L, 125L, 132L, 128L, 94L, 102L, 111L, 128L, 92L, 
104L, 94L, 100L, 102L, 128L, 90L, 103L, 157L, 107L, 91L, 117L, 
123L, 120L, 106L, 101L, 120L, 127L, 162L, 112L, 98L, 154L, 165L, 
99L, 68L, 123L, 91L, 93L, 101L, 56L, 95L, 136L, 129L, 130L, 107L, 
140L, 107L, 121L, 90L, 99L, 127L, 118L, 122L, 129L, 110L, 80L, 
127L, 158L, 126L, 134L, 102L, 94L, 108L, 83L, 114L, 117L, 111L, 
112L, 116L, 141L, 175L, 92L, 106L, 105L, 95L, 126L, 65L, 99L, 
102L, 109L, 153L, 100L, 81L, 121L, 108L, 137L, 106L, 88L, 89L, 
101L, 122L, 121L, 93L)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your calculation was almost right, R uses this:

```
#max(min(x), Q1 - (IQR(x)*1.5)) #lower whisker
#min(max(x), Q3 + (IQR(x)*1.5)) #upper whisker
```

That's why, it picks the `max/min` between the `min(x)/max(x)`, and the standard formula.

Here an example:

```
my_data <- mtcars$mpg

bp <- boxplot(my_data)
bp$stats
# [1,] 10.40 # lower whisker
# [2,] 15.35
# [3,] 19.20 # == median(my_data)
# [4,] 22.80
# [5,] 33.90 # upper whisker


max(min(my_data,na.rm=T), as.numeric(quantile(my_data, 0.25)) - (IQR(my_data)*1.5))
#[1] 10.4 #lower whisker
min(max(my_data,na.rm=T), as.numeric(quantile(my_data, 0.75)) + (IQR(my_data)*1.5))
#[1] 33.9 # upper whisker
```

Comment: I ran this line but the it returned 45  max(min(mydata),93-(IQR(mydata)*1.5))
[1] 45

Comment: No, there are no NA values and do I add the vector in the question itself?

Comment: The Vector mydata is of length 500, would you like me to paste that here?

Comment: Yes  on running   quantile(mydata,0.25)
25% 
 93

Comment: ok this is weird, because you can get `min=56`, only if you exclude `0` and `44` from `mydata`, `min(mydata[!mydata %in% c(0, 44)])`. And with this the correct result. Why this is happening is beyond me at the moment.

Comment: Already tried that... I went as far as re-downloading the data-set... Just incase

Answer (score 1):

I think there are few things to clarified. The first thing is that you should always provide a reproducible example for helping people to help you.
An outlier is defined as a data point that is located outside the whiskers of the boxplot (e.g: outside 1.5 times the interquartile range above the upper quartile and bellow the lower quartile).
The correct way to figure out how this work is simulating some Student's T data under a pre-specified a random number generator state.

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- rt(100, df = 3)
boxplot(mydata)
summary(mydata)
```

[image: Boxplot]

Then we can calculate the interquartile range and the lower and upper bounds for outliers according to the rule in the text above

```
t <- as.vector(summary(mydata))
iqr.range <- t[5]-t[2]
upper_outliers <- t[5]+iqr.range*1.5
lower_outliers <- t[2]-iqr.range*1.5
```

Let's check the data which are defined as outliers, while the boxplot whiskers are the data points immediately before/after the lower/upper boundaries.

```
 mydata[mydata<lower_outliers]
 [1] -3.527006 -2.959327 -2.754192
 mydata[mydata>upper_outliers]
 [1] 3.080302 3.527205
```

Comment: Sorry about that I've edited the question and added the link to the dataset